# array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array Snappy Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

Estoy intentando crear un PDF y para ello necesito una fecha que viene dentro del request de la URL. Y esa fecha intento pasarlo como parametro en **Snappy** en Laravel. Pero me aparace este error **array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array**

Este es mi codigo

```
public function generatePDF(Request $request)
    {
        $fecha = $request->get('fecha');
        return PDF::loadView('vistapdf',$fecha)->download('Reporte.pdf');
    }
```

Y despues de eso como puedo capturar la fecha en la vista? Con solo llamarlo funcionaria? Es decir algo como esto

```
<?php
     echo "<h1>$fecha</h1>";
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

loadView esta esperando como segundo parametro un array.

```
public function generatePDF(Request $request)
{
   $fecha = $request->get('fecha');
   $data = arra('fecha' => $fecha);
   return PDF::loadView('vistapdf',$data)->download('Reporte.pdf');
}

en la vista lo usuarias asi:

{{ $data->fecha }}
```

Comment: La modifique un poco para colocarla como `return PDF::loadView('vistapdf', array('fecha' => $fecha))->download('Reporte.pdf');`  Pero en general es lo mismo.